# benchmarking the performance of threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, benchmarking

I am experimenting stuff and trying to calculate the time taken to create N threads and doing some simple operation in the thread.

I have a variable initialized to `0` and waiting till it reaches the value N, where N is the number of threads. That way, I can ensure that all the threads are done executing atleast till the part before the return statement(last line of that function).

I am guessing that numbers `[0,N]` where `N is the number of threads we want to create` should be output in some random order but printing some stuff that doesnt make sense(addresses, may be). My question is why are the number not being printed in a random fashion from 0 to N

Code here:

```
void* increment(void *);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
   if(argc != 2) {
    cout<<"Please provide the number of threads to create" <<endl;
    return -1;
}

int nthreads = atoi(argv[1]);
pthread_t thread_ids[nthreads];
int count = 0;

struct timeval timeStart, timeEnd;
gettimeofday(&timeStart, NULL);

int i = 0;
while(i < nthreads)
{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    if( pthread_create( &thread_ids[i] , NULL , increment , (void*) &count) < 0)
    {
        error("could not create thread");
        return 1;
    }
    ++i;
}

while(count < nthreads)
{
    cout<<"Waiting !"<<endl;
    //repeat
}

gettimeofday(&timeEnd, NULL);

for(i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)
    pthread_join(thread_ids[i], NULL);

std::cout << "This piece of code took "
<< ((timeEnd.tv_sec - timeStart.tv_sec) * 1000000L + timeEnd.tv_usec - timeStart.tv_usec) << " us to execute."
<< std::endl;

 return 0;
}

void* increment(void *i)
{
  int *p = (int*)i;
  cout<<*p<<endl<<std::flush;
  fflush(stdout);
  *p = *p + 1;
  return 0;
 }
```

Not sure whats wrong in this piece of code. Any pointers?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Unsynchronized, non-atomic, non-readonly access to a shared object in multiple threads is undefined behavior.

Comment: Can I safely assume that the way Im doing is the right way to calculate the time taken by all the threads to do that operation ?

Comment: @listen: You can "safely assume" absolutely nothing about your program if `nthreads` is greater than zero.

Answer (score 2):

The POSIX standard is quite clear that an object may not be accessed in one thread while it is, or might be, modified in another.